# Oracle backup batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, cmd, database-backups

I ask you for advice with my script for backup Oracle database 12c. I attached picture with code and with cmd screen.
When I run this script, the variables is making have set up, connecting to the database and then RMAN did nothing. Any solution? Thank you.

```
@echo off
echo Automatic Backup Oracle
pushd .
SET ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1
SET ORACLE_SID=ORCL
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo ORACLE_HOME : %ORACLE_HOME%
echo ORACLE_SID  : %ORACLE_SID%
echo ----------------------------------------------------
RMAN TARGET system/password 
run {
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 'c:\backup\%F';
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'c:\backup\%d_%T_%u';
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO 'c:\backup\SNCFORCL.ORA';
}
run {
backup database;
backup archivelog all delete input;
}    
PAUSE
```

When I run this script, the variables are set up, it connects to the database and then RMAN does nothing.

In this image is cmd result:

[image: batch output]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cmd.exe doesn't run non cmd.exe code like that, you should probably write your RMAN script code to a `.rcv` file and use the `cmdfile=YourScriptFileName.rcv` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need split in two files: a batch file and RMAN scrip

Batch file: **backup.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Automatic Backup Oracle
pushd .
SET ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1
SET ORACLE_SID=ORCL
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo ORACLE_HOME : %ORACLE_HOME%
echo ORACLE_SID  : %ORACLE_SID%
echo ----------------------------------------------------
RMAN TARGET / @file.rman log=backup.log
```

Script RMAN called **file.rman** or another name

```
run {
backup database;
backup archivelog all delete input;
}
```

This part is setup:

```
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 'c:\backup\%F';
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'c:\backup\%d_%T_%u';
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO 'c:\backup\SNCFORCL.ORA';
```

Can be removed from the script and run once for each bank.
Once configured, the settings are permanent.

So, your script need two files: **backup.bat** and **file.rman**

Answer (score 1):

Like Compo said, put your RMAN Script into a .rcv file and run it with this command, like yours above but with an `@<rcv>`, and maybe logging would be good:

`RMAN TARGET / @myRMANbackup.rcv log=myRMANlogfile.log`